# Footer Table Note

Tags: footer

I am fairly new to the footer syntax in LaTeX, I want to make a footer of a similar  manner as the one shown in the attached picture. In addition to having a fixed position on the bottom of every page it also needs to auto-update per page basis. If you can lend any help it would be greatly appreciated!!

[image]

Comment: Welcome to TeX SX! What should change on each page – only the page number?

Comment: Yes! It should be just the page number!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wih the help of `fancyhdr` for the customized footer,  `tabularx` to make the table as wide as the textwidth, `lastpage` to get the number of the last page and `xcolor` to adjust the colors of the table:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{lastpage}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\definecolor{mylightgray}{RGB}{240,240,240}
\definecolor{mydarkgray}{RGB}{130,130,130}
\usepackage{blindtext} % Ony for example document
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyfoot[C]{%
          \color{mydarkgray}
          \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{|c|X|c|}
          \hline
          \rowcolor{mylightgray}Filename & Description & Pages\\
          \hline
          DM-TEMPLATE.doxc & \textbf{Report Title} & Page \thepage\ of \pageref{LastPage}\\
          \hline
          \end{tabularx}%
}

\begin{document}
\blinddocument
\end{document}
```

Comment: I didn't even know some of these command existed! Thank you very much!!